# Windows of the anki program are not correctly being displayed

Tags: display-settings, dwm

## The context

I use `dwm` as my main windows manager and `anki` to create flashcards.

## The problem

Some windows of the `anki` program are not correctly being displayed (see image or gif below)

**Gif**

[image]

**Screenshot**

[image]

## The question

How can I make `anki` windows to be correctly displayed when using `dwm`?

## Additional context

1. At a first glance I thought that it was because of the windows manager that I use (`dwm`) but then I tried opening `anki` while using `i3` the problem still occurred.
2. I tried searching a similar issue on the Internet but didn't find any meaningful information. These are some of the searches that I performed

- `"anki" "dwm" bad windows display`
- `"anki" "dwm" bad windows drawing`
- `"anki" "linux" bad windows display`
- `"anki" "linux" bad windows drawing`

3. I've previously used `anki` on `dwm` and didn't have any issue. Unfortunately, I don't remember the previous version I was using. Because of this, I can't know whether this issue is because an `anki` update or not.

Comment: This looks like it could be an issue with the graphics driver in general...

Comment: I've created [a post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1910828) in the Arch Linux forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was helped in the Anki forum after creating a [post](https://forums.ankiweb.net/t/buttons-and-windows-are-not-correctly-being-displayed-in-the-latest-releases/369).

I solved the issue by executing

```
$ ANKI_NOHIGHDPI=1 anki
```

You can find further information on this issue in the related links that were posted by `addons_zz` in his reply to my [post in the Anki forum](https://forums.ankiweb.net/t/buttons-and-windows-are-not-correctly-being-displayed-in-the-latest-releases/369).